# Remove Unintended Git Tracking

Tags: git

At some point: I accidentally started tracking with git my Desktop!  Now when I do `git status` from the desktop it shows a bunch of things to be committed.

I never intended to track my Desktop.  How do I remove Git from this?

Comment: How come your Desktop is under a directory that is tracked by git?

Comment: @Leon I don't know.  I did it accidentally probably about two years ago when I was learning about Git.

Comment: Have you tried `git reset`?